# Cómo convertir con python un archivo mp4 a mp3 [320kbps]

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg

Lo he intentado usando:

```
import ffmpeg

    stream = ffmpeg.input(name+'.mp4')
    stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, name+'.mp3')
    ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

Además que no encontre la opción para convertirlo a exactamente 320kbps

¿Tiene que el audio del video mp4 tener obligatoriamente 320kbps?
o ¿Se puede convertir sin que el archivo de audio original sea inferior?

Para lo que dije mas o menos me baso en los programas convertidores/descargadores que dudo mucho que el audio del video sea 320kbps pero siempre hay la opcion y siempre lo convierte a 320kbps

Comment: Al margen del código concreto, quería señalar una cuestión más bien teórica. Si la fuente tiene menos de 320kbps, aunque puedas convertir el resultado a 320kbps obviamente no por ello vas a obtener mejor calidad. De donde no hay no se puede sacar. El problema es similar a hacer zoom en una imagen de baja resolución "sin que se vean pixelazos". Es necesario resintetizar la información que falta, de alguna, forma, y según el método que por debajo usen las librerías el resultado será raramente mejor al del original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las diferencias entre ambos formatos, es que uno es exclusivo de audio `.mp3` y `.mp4` puede contener audio, video e incluso otros datos como subtitulos, etc.

Yo cuando he tenido que realizar esta operación utilizo la librería `moviepy`, puedes instalarla mediante el siguiente comando:

```
pip install moviepy
```

Una vez lo hemos instalado, podemos cargar un archivo `.mp4` y depués guardarlo como `.mp3`

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

name = "dirección/donde_se_encuentra/el.mp4"

#Cargamos el fichero .mp4
clip = mp.VideoFileClip(name)

#Lo escribimos como audio y `.mp3`
clip.audio.write_audiofile("transformado_a.mp3")
```

Esta librería es de edición, así que tienes una gran cantidad de métodos para cambiar las características del audio, puedes [ver aquí su documentación](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/)

En concreto a la hora de guardar el audio, puedes usar varios parámetros como la **codificación**, **bitrate**, etc. Esto se puede ver especificamente, en [este apartado de la documentación](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/AudioClip.html)

### bitrate

Los audios no tienen *obligatoriamente* el por que tener un bitrate de 320kbps, de hecho varía de unos a otros. La mayoría de los audios descargados que han sido comprimidos en internet **tienen un bitrate de 128kbps** por segundo. Pero hay a personas que esa calidad les puede parecer inaceptable.

Tu puedes guardarlo como quieras con el parámetro `bitrate`, tendrías que cambiar lo siguiente:

```
clip.audio.write_audiofile("transformado_a.mp3", bitrate="320k")
```

### Advertencia

A pesar de que su desarrollo y mantenimiento es bueno como se puede ver en [**pypi**](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/) Las versiones de Python para las que está testado, la máxima es Python 3.6 Aunque yo lo uso con Python 3.7 y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Hola, obtengo este error https://prnt.sc/w3xiqn  , puedes ayudarme por favor?